# return float value in summaryType ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want display a float value in summaryType in ExtJs grid.
But display int value

this mu code:

```
.
.
.
summaryType: function()
              {

                g++;
                 //return parseFloat(funcs[g-1]());
                return parseFloat(15.2);

            }
.
.
.
```

> value returned of this code is: 15

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `summaryRenderer` config:

```
summaryRenderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,000.00'),
```

Comment: this code return 15.00 number.
for example target is 15.2

Comment: Then change the format to `0,000.0` or to '0,000.#' if the decimal part is optional.